# Make Http Request Observation and return anm Observable with the result

Tags: rxjs

I have the following scenario: There is a service which is called "ContextProvider" that holds information regarding the context of the applicaiton (Logged In User, Things he can acess, etc). Right now I am observing this as following:

```
this.contextProvider.Context.subscribe(context => {
    //Do Something
})
```

Now I have a service that will also be observable. I want this service to observe the context and return an observable. This would be easy with the map function:

```
let observable = this.contextProvider.Context.pipe(map(context => {
    let aux: number = somevar + someothervar;
    return aux;
})) //observable variable now holds the type Observable<number>
```

My scenario is a little bit more complex, because in order to fetch the result, I have to make an Http call, which is also an observable/promise:

```
let observable = this.contextProvider.Context.pipe(map(context => {
    return this.httpClient.get<number>("Some URL").pipe(take(1));
})); //observable var now holds Obsevable<Observable<number>>
```

How can I make the "observable" var hold Observable?

EDIT: The URL value depends on the some values of the "context" variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right your problem, you need to use `concatMap` for this case, like this

```
this.contextProvider.Context.pipe(
  concatMap(context => {
    return this.httpClient.get<number>("Some URL" + context.someData);
}));
```

You can find more patterns around the use of Observables with http calls in [this article](https://medium.com/@enrico.piccinin/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. I was trying just now flatMap instead and it seems to work, but I surely will look onto it.

Comment: `flatMap` (aka `mergeMap`) and `switchMap` will work in this case, but the best choice is usually `concatMap`.